# Is there any way to load google maps api from custom plugin before the plugin codes executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing a google map integrated plugin and i want that, let google maps api v3 is loaded from my plugin before the plugin codes executed.
I tried to use $getscript but didn't work, i tried to put all codes into a function (called initialize()) and execute this function when the plugin activated but this time, my plugins' options are corrupted and i get errors. I tried `appendto()` method but nothing changed.
I've searched many places to solve this issue, but no success..
Is there any proper way to solve this problem? thanks...

I am calling my plugin like that:

```
$('div#mapid').plugin_name({opt1:'val1',opt2:'val2',opt3:'val3'});
```

and my plugin is coded like that

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.plugin_name = function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend(true,{
      // default plugin options
    }, options);

    //plugin codes

  }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Maybe a typo, but you call your plugin first `plugin_name` and later `pluginname`.

Comment: @putvande it was just for illustration, my plugin name is one word, so there is no problem on there, i corrected on question.